# FragmentPagerAdapter cannot be insantiated but it is NOT abstract

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

```
final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

I'm getting an error that says FragmentPagerAdapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated... except that my FragmentPagerAdapter is not abstract.

Here is the adapter:

```
public class FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

It also says the class here is never used, but IT IS. This is the method I use in my MainActivity onCreate:

```
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_sun));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_calendar));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

    });

    viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.getString("fragment") != null) {
            if ("fragment2".equals(bundle.getString("fragment"))) {
            /*Log.w(getClass().toString(), bundle.getString("fragment"));*/
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            } else {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

What the heck is going on!?

Comment: It would seem that you have `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` - which is `abstract` - imported in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Change `public class FragmentPagerAdapter` to `public class SantaFeBoundPagerAdapter` or something else distinctive.

Comment: Ah thanks guys. Yikes. I copied the class into a new project and Android Studio auto-imported the support fragment manager.